# Bootstrap 3 table-responsive not working with col-lg-12

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

```
<div class="col-lg-12 table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Sender</th>
                <th width="60%">Messages</th>
                <th>Date/Time</th>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This code is not working, please help me out with it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use those classes together. You need to wrap the div with the class `table-responsive` in a container with the class `col-lg-12`.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Sender</th>
                    <th width="60%">Messages</th>
                    <th>Date/Time</th>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```